# How to both let script window display its output and capture its StdOut at the end?

Tags: c#, stdout, io-redirection

When I redirect stdout, the new script's process window does not show all the printing (obviously, as it's redirected...).

Is there a way to both show the printings in the script window (be it PowerShell or Python) and also capture its output after the process ends?

```
var process = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = path,
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true, // I want to capture stdout
    }
};

using (process) {
    process.Start();

    process.WaitForExit();

    var stdout = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // I do have the output in stdout now, but the script's window hasn't shown anything while it was running.
    // It makes me sad :-(
}
```

Comment: Its times like that you wish windows was more like unix, "tee" solves this beautifully